# How to read ActiveRecord configuration from own gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I need to call "establish_connection" method from my own gem, but ActiveRecord::Base.configurations is [].

I made work around:

```
module Bitrix
  class Database < ActiveRecord::Base
    @config = YAML.load(File.read('config/database.yml'))
    self.abstract_class = true
    establish_connection @config["bitrix_#{Rails.env}"]
  end
end
```

But why I can't access to AR config without opening file directly? I tried to use `establish_connection :"bitrix_#{Rails.env}"` and got this error:

> /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:257:in `resolve_symbol_connection': 'bitrix_development' database is not configured. Available: [] (ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All config is available in:

```
Rails.application.config.database_configuration
```

So you'd have:

```
db_config = Rails.application.config.database_configuration
db_config['development']
```

Answer (score 0):

Opening any file is not needed here. `ActiveRecord` needs however proper configuration to know how to connect to given database, e.g:

```
{"template"=>"template0", "adapter"=>"postgresql", 
"encoding"=>"UTF8", "database"=>"database", "pool"=>50, 
"username"=>"rails", "password"=>nil}
```

Loading `database.yml` parses `yaml` into hash with environment names as keys and their configurations as values.

```
config = YAML.load(File.read('config/database.yml'))
establish_connection config["bitrix_#{Rails.env}"]
```

returns more or less the same hash with `adapter`, `user` and `password` which are essential to connect to database.